# Using TextIO.Write to create new bucket if isn't exist in Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to check a file created in a ParDo is different to a stored in the GCS.

To do this I try to read the file and compare their differences.

```
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(c.getPipelineOptions());
        try {
            PCollection<String> lines = p.apply(
                    TextIO.Read
                            .named("Read Section on GS")
                            .from("gs://failbucket/foo/boo/ret.txt"))
                    .apply(ParDo
                            .of(new Util.viewDifferences2(c.element))
                            .named("only different"));

            lines.apply(
                    TextIO.Write.named("Write Document Different")
                            .to(pathGS)
                            .withSuffix(".json"));

            p.run();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            p = Pipeline.create(c.getPipelineOptions());
            PCollection<String> lines = p.apply(Create.of(sectionContent));

            lines.apply(TextIO.Write.named("Write new Document")
                    .to("gs://failbucket/foo/boo/ret").withSuffix(".txt"));
            p.run();
        }
```

Initially the file does not exist so Exception but when try created have this message "Output path does not exist or is not writeable"

Do you know how I can create entire new path?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the option withoutValidation which voids the validation but it will create the corresponding buckets in gs. But it will throw exception if the parent bucket does not exists

In your case, if "failbucket" bucket does not exist it will throw below error.

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to write to GCS path gs://failbucket/foo/boo/ret/xxx.txt

But if the "failbucket" bucket exists in your gs project, then it will create foo/boo/ buckets if those buckets does not exist.

In your case the below should go fine, if "failbucket" bucket is exists in your gs

```
            lines.apply(TextIO.Write.named("Write new Document")
                .to("gs://failbucket/foo/boo/ret")
                .withoutValidation()
                .withSuffix(".txt"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, is there any way to check if a file exist in the GCS. for not to pass through to the exception

Comment: @mitchell.p Consider using [com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.Gcsutil.fileSize](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/e872e0b55b131df432bdf3d34879a78dfdbba1c0/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/util/GcsUtil.java#L204) method, which is close to what you need. There's also a [GcsUtil.bucketExists](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/e872e0b55b131df432bdf3d34879a78dfdbba1c0/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/util/GcsUtil.java#L279) method.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your exception handling code is submitting a Dataflow pipeline whose only purpose is to create an empty file in Google Cloud Storage.

This is not particularly efficient. Instead, you can use [Google Cloud Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/) directly to interact with your GCS buckets. This API is much more efficient and comprehensive for this purpose. For example, you can use this API before starting your main Dataflow pipeline.

Another approach is to try out the [`gsutil`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) tool. This command-line tool has similar capabilities of interacting with your GCS buckets. You can also invoke it from your Java program, or separately, before starting the Java program.

An approach of disabling validation on `TextIO` in Dataflow is generally discouraged. This validation may provide the benefit of catching errors fast and early, before starting the execution of your pipeline in the Cloud Platform. That said, the validation should be disabled in rare cases where prerequisites cannot be verified at the job submission time.